# Recursion method to display the directory structure of a path (Java)

Tags: java, recursion

Our teacher gave us question to Write a recursive method to display the directory structure of a path.

He want the output to look like this :

```
           testdir
           +--f1
           +--d2
              +--d22
                 +f221
               +f212
               +f211
            +--f2
            +--d1
               +--f12
```

I used this method :

```
package Task;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recursive {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDirectory = new File(" . "); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDirectory);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dirct) {           
        File[] myfiles = dirct.listFiles();                 
                for (File file : myfiles) {                     
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {                           
                    //it worked when i used file.getCanonicalPath()); but file.getName()); does not work
                        System.out.println("directory : " + file.getName());                            
                        displayDirectoryContents(file);                         
                    } 
                else {
                    //it worked when i used file.getCanonicalPath()); but file.getName()); does not work
                        System.out.println(" files : " + file.getName());
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

The getName does not work and give me an erorr (

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lab16.displayDirectoryContents(lab16.java:17)
    at lab16.main(lab16.java:10)
)

Comment: OK.  Is there a question here?

Comment: it does not work with getName

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work?"

Comment: **Please** read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

i've rewritten algorithm and it works with .getName() without any problem. I didn't do any indentations tho.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Recursive {
    private static void TraverseDirectory(File[] files) {
        if (files.length == 0) return;

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) System.out.println(file.getName());
            else {
                // is DIR
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                TraverseDirectory(file.listFiles());
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File cur_dir = new File("/");
        TraverseDirectory(cur_dir.listFiles());
    }
}
```

EDIT: after you edited your question, I can now see what was the problem. You weren't returning anything when the content of the directory was empty (it was null). Therefore, it couldn't traverse null value.